# Verticaly centered equal height columns when some divs are nested?

Tags: css

I need equal height columns which vertically centre there content. When each column div is a direct descendant of a container this is easy to do with display table: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKzOrv

However I have nested divs. Is it still possible to achieve this layout without modifying my markup?

UPDATE - As I'm supporting IE9+ I cant use flexbox.

```css
.cont {
  width: 500px;
}
.depth1 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: table;
}
.depth2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.a {
  background: blue;
}
.b {
  background: green;
}
.c {
  background: orange;
}
.d {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="depth1">
    <div class="depth2 a">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="depth2 b">
      B
      <br>Wrap
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="depth1">
    <div class="depth2 c">
      C
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>Wrap
    </div>
    <div class="depth2 d">
      D
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @j08691 Yes Ive updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with `Flexbox`, just use `display: flex` on all child `div` elements except on `.c` and add `align-items: center` on `.depth2`

```css
.cont {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
}
.depth1 {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}
.depth2 {
  width: 50%;
}
.depth2:not(.c) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.a {
  background: blue;
}
.b {
  background: green;
}
.c {
  background: orange;
}
.d {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="depth1">
    <div class="depth2 a">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="depth2 b">
      B
      <br>Wrap
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="depth1">
    <div class="depth2 c">
      C
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>Wrap
    </div>
    <div class="depth2 d">
      D
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```